# Why is my function not giving me an answer when I type a big number?

Tags: python

```
def myfunc():

    number = int(input('Enter a number : '))
    x = 3
    d = [2]
    g = []

    while  0<=number<=1:
        return 'There is no prime number'

    while 0>number:
        return 'There is no prime number'

    while number == 2:
        return 'Prime number : 2 '

    while x<=number:
        for y in range(3,x,2):
            if x%y == 0:
                x += 2
                break
        else:
                d.append(x)
                x += 2

    for c in d:
        if number%c == 0:
            g.append(c)
        else:
            pass

    return max(g)

myfunc()
```

Input:
<kbd>`600851475143`</kbd>

I typed that and my function didn't respond to me.

This is the code that I am running. No problem is coming up, but it doesn't give me an answer either. I can't find the problem.

Comment: Do the math.  You're doing 300 BILLION loops.  Even on a fast processor, that's going to take a very long time.  By the way, when checking for primes, you don't have to check through `x`.  You can stop at `math.sqrt(x)`.

Comment: `print()` is your friend…

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: you have too many loops. You should find first value which divides `number` - i.e. `x` - and then `number/x` gives you max value which divides `number` and you don't need run last `for`-loop and `max(g)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many loops and it runs very, very long.

If you want to get only max value which divides `number` then you can find min value which divides `number` - ie. `x` - and `number // x` gives you max value which divide `number`.

Also you don't have check all values but only to `math.sqrt(number)`
which you can also write as `number**0.5`

```
def myfunc():

    number = int(input('Enter a number : '))

    if number <= 1:
        return 'There is no prime number'

    if number == 2:
        return 'Prime number : 2 '

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    
    for x in range(3, int(number**0.5), 2):
        if number % x == 0:
            return number // x 

    return number  # prime

myfunc()
```

And now `600851475143` gives result `8462696833` in few milliseconds.

because

```
8462696833 = 600851475143 / 71
```

so it has to check only ~36 numbers: `2` and `3, 5, 7, 9, ... ,71`